# C++ ODBC SQL_ATTR_PARAMS_STATUS_PTR missing in header

Tags: c++, binding, odbc

I am trying to bind a structure with Rowset binding ala:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215456(v=sql.80).aspx

THIS IS AN MSDN TYPO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in sqlext.h, so:

```
 #include "sqlext.h"
```

Unless you wish to have the difference between sql.h and sqlext.h as your specialist subject in a quiz program, you are better off always #including both of them, without thinking.

Comment: Hmmm... its not in MS SDK v5.0 of that header file (or sql.h). perhpas you could just post its hex/decimal value?

Comment: @Mike It is there in v7.0 of the SDK, which is current. It's part of ODBC 3.0 - it sounds like you have an extremely old development environment - you should really upgrade. For what it's worth, its decimal value is 20.

Comment: I installed v6 last year which put v5 in the same folder. I will look for v7. Many thanks

Comment: @Mike Actually, I just noticed that your question title and text don't match. SQL_ATTR_ROW_STATUS_PTR has the value 25. There is no SQL_ATTR_PARAMS_STATUS_PTR, it is SQL_ATTR_PARAM_STATUS_PTR.

Comment: Yes that's a long night artifact! I just realized this is an MSDN Typo (see the link). Thank you so much for the help.